# Updated or improved WebView when targeting Android 4.0 and later

Tags: android, webview

I'm developing an app which makes heavy use of an Android `WebView` which displays some quite heavy-weight responsive web content. On certain devices I'm seeing strange rendering or CSS issues. And in general, performance across the board could be better.

The `WebView` class has been available since API level 1. On another popular mobile development platform, the equivalent functionality has been provided by a succession of classes, later versions of which have improved rendering engines. Hence when targeting newer versions of the platform, one tends to use the more modern web view class, which is why I'm asking here.

Is there a newer/shiny-er `WebView` class I could or should be using if I'm targeting Android 4.0 and later?

All web searches just seem to throw up the original `WebView` and I've had API "discoverability" issues with Android before. It seems sometimes you just need to be *"in the know"* about the existence of newer classes to make best possible use of the platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android, WebView doesn't have any successor classes for newer versions. The device only possesses a single version of WebView, and this is what being used by all apps. Since Android Lollipop [WebView is updated automatically via Play Store](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview), that means, all the improvements made to the rendering engine are automatically engaged after an update.

You will find yourself in a situation, when your app needs to support several different versions of WebView in the wild (WebView in Android KitKat will never be updated, for example), and you should handle this situation exactly the same way as browser versions diversity--by testing, whether a particular web platform feature is supported and providing a workaround implementation if needed.